# Set orientation - native camera/maps some other apps too

Tags: android

I am developing an application to take photos using the Android native camera and load maps, etc.
The orientation of the maps has been changing as I change it, but what I actually need is to have only landscape orientation even on native apps since my whole application is landscape-only.

But how can I set the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file you specify the acceptable orientations for your application.

To force your activity to remain in landscape mode simply include the `android:screenOrientation` tag in your activity's definition tag.

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: how this can't be applied to native apps and i am launching them via intent. they are not a part of my app they are external app.

Comment: you can't, you can only specify the orientation on your own activities, unless the other activities provide you the ability to specify their orientation using `intent.putExtra` although I've never seen that

Comment: ya know that but any work around or any solution might be there?

Comment: the only work around I can think of would be to use root permissions to override the signal coming from the accelerometer.  **or** see if the native app you want is included in the android github source tree, if it is extract the source, include it in your app and specify the orientation

Comment: will try any other work around and will post the solution if i succeed